# Why is stepsize 0.00000000 for certain symbols on Binance?

Tags: binance

I noticed stepsize is 0.00000000 for WRXUSDT in the Spot market.
What does it really mean? Shouldn't it be at least >0 ?

Also, whats the difference of ticksize in 'LOT_SIZE' and 'MARKET_LOT_SIZE'? Is that the ticksize limit order and market order?

Information from the binance api on exchangeInfo endpoint:
[{'filterType': 'LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.10000000', 'maxQty': '900000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.10000000'}, {'filterType': 'MARKET_LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00000000', 'maxQty': '692342.01250000', 'stepSize': '0.00000000'}]